# Is there a way to reorder cluster resource group after pcs resource add

Tags: cluster-computing, high-availability, rhel6, pacemaker, corosync

By default my resource group contains 3 resources which are added in proper order as required.

```
   [root@2 ~]# pcs resource
    Resource Group: RES-1
      RES_a1    (ocf::abc:cde): Started 
      RES_a1-p1 (ocf::f:I2):    Started 
      RES_a2    (ocf::hjs:f4):  Started
```

As per requirements new resource can be added, Now i want all those resource to be added before the last resource (RES_a2) so that during failover they start / stop in the order i need.

Working solutions found so far (but i feel this is not the correct way)

Solution 1 :

Before adding new resource , delete the last resource and then again add the new resource and then the last resource again.  This is working and the order is also maintained.

Solution 2 :

Manually editing the  cib.xml file using cibadmin --query  and cibadmin --replace , This also works fine. But this is more of a hack kind and not the proper way todo.

I want this to be automated and hence require some stable commands.

Other things tried, but not working :

pcs constraint order start res1 then res2

Answer (score 0):

You can reorder the resources inside a resourcegroup using this command (example based on your resource group), if you now want to add a resource RES_a1-p2, then just add that resource and it will go to the end after RES_a2 and then execute this command:

pcs resource group add RES-1 RES_a2 --after RES_a1-p2

or

pcs resource group add RES-1 RES_a1-p2 --after RES_a1-p1

or

pcs resource group add RES-1 RES_a1-p2 --before RES_a2